# How to simulate terminal input without TIOCSTI in Python?

Tags: python, terminal, pty, fcntl

I want to run a command in a pseudo-terminal.
I know that I could use `fcntl.ioctl()` with `TIOCSTI` but TIOCSTI has been [removed from my system](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-hardening/20221015041626.1467372-2-keescook@chromium.org/). However, there has to be a different way to do it, otherwise terminals just wouldn't work. This subject is not very well documented online, so even after some extensive googling I wasn't able to find anything useful.

Here is the code I used before, in case it would help:

```py
import fcntl
import termios

def run_on_pty(pty, command):
    for char in command:
        fcntl.ioctl(pty, termios.TIOCSTI, char)
```